# configuration CAS with LDAP active Directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I am using [CAS server](http://www.jasig.org/cas) version 3.5.2 and after I configured it to connect to an LDAP server I got this message. Anyone have a clue about what is happening? My LDAP server is `pfeserver.pfe.dz`

```
 :org.springframework.ldap.UncategorizedLdapException: Uncategorized
 exception occured during LDAP processing; nested exception is
 javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot parse url:
 "ldaps://pfeserver.pfe.dz" [Root exception is
 java.net.MalformedURLException: Not an LDAP URL:
 "ldaps://pfeserver.pfe.dz"]
```

Comment: what kind of Java Runtime Environment are you running for CAS? What's the platform?